# Wrapper to allocate a pty (opposite to nohup)

Tags: pty

I have a command `foo` that (for reasons we need not go into) needs to have a pty allocated, i.e. `foo` succeeds but `nohup foo` fails.

What is the easiest way to allocate a pty when there is not one? `screen -D -m foo` seems like overkill, an does not return an exit code (which I need). Save for the exit code, it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While @thrig's answer would probably work with `expect` (and I upvoted it), I made [a tiny modification](https://github.com/abligh/pty/commit/51a21a7fd28c411dce2d04623967f430d589e762) to `pty.c` from Stevens' [Advanced Programming in the UNIX® Environment](http://www.apuebook.com/) to return the exit code if `-r` is specified. The result is [here](http://www.github.com/abligh/pty). This seems to do the trick with minimal fuss.

Answer (score 2):

Use `expect`, e.g.

```
#!/usr/bin/env expect -f

spawn -noecho ssh localhost "sleep 3; false"
catch wait status
exit [lindex $status 3]
```

Comment: This gives me `/usr/bin/env: ‘expect -f’: No such file or directory`.

Comment: @CMCDragonkai some unix have broken `env` commands so you'll need to on those systems either change to something without a broken `env` or use the fully qualified path to wherever your  vendor puts the `expect` command.

Answer (score 1):

```
script /dev/null
```

is the easiest, most portable solution (though still not available by default on android or busybox).

It works fine even when its stdin and stdout are not ttys.

Comment: `script /dev/null foo` would work on BSD (including macOS). On Linux the syntax is `script -qc foo /dev/null`, as suggested in https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/249726